# org.eclipse.jetty 9.4.30v plugins giving issue missing constraint import package javax.servlet version "[3.1.0,4.00)" in Java 11

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, java-11

-We are upgrading our application from java 8 to Java 11
For multiple jetty org.eclipse.jetty 9.4.30v  plugins giving dependency issue missing constraint import package javax.servlet version "[3.1.0,4.00)".

-javax.servlet version 3.1.0 is already present and selected.

Still why it is giving missing import error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.